# How to sum row cell to the row cell?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hye,
     Is it possible sum the one row cell to the other row cell 
Example:

```
id name open receive close
1  jon   0     500    500
1  jon  500    600    1100
1  jon  1100   400    1500
```

first row close amount plus to the next row open amount.

Comment: @jarlh can u explain more

Comment: @jon:How are you ordering rows,its not as simple as saying first row,second row,you need to have some col to order by

Comment: Please explain question in details.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT id,name,SUM(open),SUM(receive),SUM(close)
FROM xxxxx?
GROUP BY id,name